# How to Add a Text/Logo under the search Bar

Tags: layout, template

How can I add a text/logo under the search bar ?  this text is here presented as the "Target Text" on the picture,

I found some post but the guy describes his way as "terrible", so I wanted to know how to do it properly

Apologies for my terrible picture !

Thanks

[image: The WEbsite]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using version 1.9.x

Open: `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml`

and add the following to the bottom of that file:

```
<?php echo $this->__('Target Text'); ?>
```

Clear cache and refresh.

[image]

Comment: or copy that template to your theme folder and edit from there